# How to override id parameter sent by jqGrid during delete

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free-jqGrid 4.14.1 to display data which has composite ids on two columns: `id` and `type`. Because jqGrid doesn't support combined keys, I added a field called `uniqueId` which contains the concatenated values of `id` and `type`:

```
$grid.jqGrid({
    url: /*ajaxListURL*/ '',
    editurl: /*ajaxActionURL*/ '',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    loadonce: false,
    colModel: [
        {name: 'uniqueId', key: true, hidden: true}, //uniqueId=id+type
        {name: 'id', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: {edithidden:true}, hidedlg: true},
        {name: 'type', editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: {edithidden:true}, hidedlg: true},
        {name: 'name', editable: true}
    ]
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: true}, {}, {}, { 
    onclickSubmit: function(options, delId){
        var rowData = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData', delId);
        return {
            id: rowData['id'],
            type: rowData['type']
        };
     }
}).jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {add: false});
```

My server expects the `id` and `type` parameters for editing or deleting a record. It cannot handle parsing `uniqueId` in order to extract `id` without some backend refactoring which I'm trying to avoid.

In order to make the edit work, I made the fields `id` and `type` editable and hidden, so that jqGrid will send both everytime I am editing a record. (this works fine)

In order to make the delete work, I implemented the `onclickSubmit` method of delete pager options, and manually added `id` and `type` values to the postData. But jqGrid overrides the value of `id` with that of the `uniqueId`

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/7wczzvur/

Is there anyway to send the actual `id` value for the `id` parameter when deleting (without renaming parameter id)?

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid **the version** which you use. The `datatype` and the usage of local data (for example, because of `loadonce: true`) is required too. Your question shows that you probably use free jqGrid in a wrong way or at least not in optimal way. Could you include more code fragments and one/two lines of demo data, which you use as input. In case of correct (optimal) usage of free jqGrid it should not contains any hidden columns. The `id` property of `prmNames` option and `id` property of `jsonReader` (`localReader` etc) informs about the name of `id` property.

Comment: @Oleg I added requested details and a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by adding

```
prmNames: { id: "uniqueId" }
```

option of jqGrid. It will inform jqGrid to use `uniqueId` instead of default `id` for sending of rowids to the server during editing operation.

Additionally you can add one more option

```
jsonReader: { id: "uniqueId" }
```

and remove absolutely unneeded hidden column `uniqueId`. In general, every hidden DOM element reduce the performance of the page and increase the size of memory used by web browser.

Additionally I'd recommend to remove `<div id="pager"></div>`, to use `pager: true` instead of `pager: '#pager'` and to remove `'#pager` parameter from `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. One can make the code more readable by usage `navOptions`, `inlineNavOptions`, `formEditing`, `formDeleting`, `searching`, `inlineEditing` etc. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/7wczzvur/26/ an example of the corresponding modification.

Finally, I'd recommend you to migrate to the current 4.15.3 version. I support only the latest version of free jqGrid. If you will find for example a bug in free jqGrid 4.14.1 then it will be fixed only in the latest code (in 4.15.4).